# Is there a way add a website slider as a hyperlink in an Outlook 2013 email or signature?

Tags: email, outlook, outlook-2013

The goal here is I've developed slider content for my site, and would like to have that same content in an email I send to a client. That content in the email is static, but the slider gets regular updates.  When a customer opens an old email, I'd like them to see the newer slider content.  I can get access to the exchange server if required.  Is there a way to do this with signatures, or other Outlook functionality?

Answer (score 0):

Outlook uses Word for rendeting message bodies. Unfortunately this fact intrudces somes restrictions to the HTML content which can be displayed in the message. You can read about supported and unsupported HTML elements, attributes, and cascading style sheets properties in the following articles:

- [Word 2007 HTML and CSS Rendering Capabilities in Outlook 2007 (Part 1 of 2)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338201(v=office.12).aspx)
- [Word 2007 HTML and CSS Rendering Capabilities in Outlook 2007 (Part 2 of 2)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338200(v=office.12).aspx)

Also Outlook prevents any JS code from ruuning on the page for the sake of security.